# Weird shaped kernels after initialization in a CNN, tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I was trying to make a CNN in pure tensorflow, and for initializing the kernels for a layer, I am using the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
kernel = tf.Variable(tf.random.truncated_normal([2,2,1,3], stddev=0.1))
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    a_value = sess.run(kernel)
    print(a_value.shape)
    print(a_value)
```

I expected to it give 3, 2*2 matrices but instead it gave the following output:

[Output Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlN67.png)

I am totally confused as I wanted to iterate over the 3, 2*2 kernels, which I am unable to do currently.
Please, help me understand the shape issue!

`tensorflow version is 1.14.0`

[Book's Excerpt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuOgG.png)

Comment: Where's your Conv layer?

Comment: There is none, I just want the initialized kernels for the first layer of my cnn, as I want to iterate over those and perform some operations!

Comment: you are clearly initializing the variable with shape `[2,2,1,3]`, how do you expect it to have magically the shape of your desired conv kernel size?

Comment: I agree, but I am following the Nick McClure's Tensorflow Cookbook and I have added an excerpt from the book in the question and that's why I have used the shape as `[2,2,1,3]` instead of `[3,2,2,1]` for getting 3, matrices of shape `[2,2,1]`.